# How can i get the image to slide into the page on my website?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

All my code gives me at the moment is a static picture. However i want it to slide in from the right hand side. can someone please tell me which jquery library i should be importing and is my code right?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mepicintro").show("fade",500);
     $("#mepicintro").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'right'},500);
  });  
</script>


<div class="eight columns">
<img id="mepicintro" src="images/my_computer.png"  width="400px" height"400px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 animation!

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#slider").addClass("in");
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  }

#slider{
  -webkit-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
  background:green;
  top:30px;
  left:100%;
 
  }

#slider.in{
  left:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Slide in!</button>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, just as one example you can use jQuery `animate()` to slide the image in without using any additional library.
Add `overflow:hidden;` to `body` to avoid displaying scrollbars and position the image outside:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#mepicintro').animate({
         'left': '300px'
     }, 500);
 });
```

```css
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#mepicintro {
    position:absolute;
    right:-300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eight columns">
    <img id="mepicintro" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" width="300px" height="300px"/>
</div>
```